# How to click the Checkbox with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, checkbox, css-selectors

I am new on selenium and in this case I'm trying build code with selenium python to click checkbox from this HTML:

```
<div class="checkBox" xpath="1"><input type="checkbox" name="registerPrivacyAgreement" id="registerPrivacyAgreement" value="1"><label for="registerPrivacyAgreement" lang="lang_9" class="privacyAgreement">I acknowledge that my data will be processed in accordance with the <a target="_blank" href="PrivacyPolicy.html">Privacy Policy.</a> &amp; <a target="_blank" href="UserAgreement.html">User Agreement.</a></label></div>
```

Snapshot of the checkbox:

[image: This Capture From chrome]

I already try to click that checkbox from xpath with this code:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[12]/div/div[4]/input").click()
```

I also tried by `ID`, & `CSS_Selector` but when I run, its doesn't click the checkbox but open newpage about UserAgreement I already try with other way but it always open newpage about UserAgreement not click the checkbox. Then I try with selenium IDE and record after that I play and then its work, but when I copy code from selnium IDE it show like this:

```
xpath=//div[@id='container']/div/div[12]/div/div[4]/label
```

Then i try back to my python code and it still open newpage about UserAgreement not click that checkbox. can someone explain me what happen and how to solve that?

Element Snapshot:

[image: Checkbox I want to click]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the HTML provided:

[image: HTML]

To click on the desired [checkbox](/questions/tagged/checkbox) ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.execute("get", {'url': 'https://www.toweroffantasy-global.com/'})
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.btn>span[lang='loginText'][scaletype]"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.register"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.checkBox input#registerPrivacyAgreement[name='registerPrivacyAgreement']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='checkBox']//input[@id='registerPrivacyAgreement']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: already try this but it became eror and give timeout msg.